# Many binary classifiers vs. single multiclass classifier

Tags: classification, multi-class

What factors should be considered when determining whether to use multiple binary classifiers or a single multiclass classifier?

For example, I'm building a model that does hand gesture classification. A simple case has 4 outputs: [None, thumbs_up, clenched_fist, all_fingers_extended]. I see two ways to approach this:

**Option 1 - Multiple binary classifiers**

1. [None, thumbs_up]
2. [None, clenched_fist]
3. [None, all_fingers_extended]

**Option 2 - Single multiclass classifier**

1. [None, thumbs_up, clenched_first, all_fingers_extended]

---

**Which approach tends to be better and in what conditions?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Option 1 may not be the best way to go; if you want to have multiple binary classifiers try a strategy called [One-vs-All](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/68Pol/multiclass-classification-one-vs-all).

In **One-vs-All** you essentially have an expert binary classifier that is *really* good at recognizing one pattern from all the others, and the implementation strategy is typically cascaded. For example:

```
  if classifierNone says is None: you are done
  else:
    if classifierThumbsUp says is ThumbsIp: you are done
    else:
      if classifierClenchedFist says is ClenchedFist: you are done
      else:
        it must be AllFingersExtended and thus you are done
```

Here is a graphical explanation of One-vs-all from Andrew Ng's course:
[image: Example]

---

**Multi-class** classifiers pros and cons:

*Pros*:

- Easy to use out of the box
- Great when you have really *many* classes

*Cons*:

- Usually slower than binary classifiers during training
- For high-dimensional problems they could really take a while to converge

*Popular methods*:

- Neural networks
- Tree-based algorithms

---

**One-vs-All** classifiers pros and cons:

*Pros*:

- Since they use binary classifiers, they are usually faster to converge
- Great when you have *a handful* of classes

*Cons*:

- It is really annoying to deal with when you have too many classes
- You really need to be careful when training to avoid class imbalances that introduce bias, e.g., if you have 1000 samples of `none` and 3000 samples of the `thumbs_up` class.

*Popular methods*:

- SVMs
- Most ensemble methods
- Tree-based algorithms

Comment: It would be better to clarify that the $h_{\theta}^i$ functions are output probabilities, and the final label is determined by $\arg\max_i  h_{\theta}^i$

Comment: That's a very good answer regarding One-vs-All & One-vs-One and it would be good to post your answer also here because the following post is more popular (but it is more or less on the same topic): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91091/one-vs-all-and-one-vs-one-in-svm.