# Anyway i can improve this multi class classification result?

Tags: classification, python, svm, scikit-learn, multi-class

I am building a multi class classification model using SVM to predict the grade for essays. **What can I do to improve the result especially for class 1 and class 3?** Their precision and recall are really bad.

Things I have done:
1. Split train:test set to 70:30 
2. Oversample the training set using smote
3. Scale the feature by using StandardScaler from Scikit-Learn
4. Perform parameter tuning by using GridSearchCv from Scikit-Learn to get the best parameter

[image: SVM result]

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your workflow makes sense but you have a problem: the number of observations is so different in all three classes. When you do your cross-validation completely random you naturally oversample the most prevalent class. Therefore you optimize the model to classify these observations correct. Intuitively, if you correctly classify a lot of the obs from class 2 your clf will achieve a decent performance. The ‚low‘ number of observations from 1 and 3 are just a ‚nice to have‘ if you classify them correctly.

One way out is sampling a [similar number observations](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) for each class or assigning [weights](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html) to the classes. Lastly, in the multi-class case remember, that you are not really training a classifier for class 1, 2 or 3 with an SVM. It's either [one-vs-all or all-vs-all](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91091/one-vs-all-and-one-vs-one-in-svm), both options are also available in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC).

This is the first thing I would try and then move maybe also to other classifiers.